# What is the fastest way to copy a 2D int array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, copy, 2d

I want to copy an array in less than time proportional to N^2. I'm just using a double for loop right now...

```
int[][] copy = new int[N][N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        copy[i][j] = original[i][j];
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: The way you're doing it, if you delete the `original` array, the `copy` will be empty too. You're just copying the references, not the values.

Comment: @HugoSousa, No I don't think so. array element are getting copied actually.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code for `Arrays.copyOf()` and see how it is done there? It is probably the best you are going to get.

Comment: @Rahul - Yes. But only because OP uses array of primitives.

Comment: @PM77-1, isn't that the point of discussion here? what's the point in assuming something which is not present in problem statement.

Comment: @PM77-1 Even if they were objects, changes to the original array wouldn't have any effect on the copy.

Comment: @OP, why do you think your current implementation is slow? Have you done any benchmarking?

Comment: @DavidConrad - OP's method would not produce a [Deep Copy](http://cs-fundamentals.com/java-programming/java-arrays-clone-shallow-deep-copy.php#java-arrays-cloning-shallow-deep-copy).

Comment: @PM77-1 Precisely as I said, changes to the `original` ***array*** wouldn't have any effect on the `copy`. The array structure is completely duplicated with no shared structure. The OP didn't ask about doing a deep copy of the elements (which are immutable `int`s anyway), but Hugo's statement that "deleting the `original` array [I've no idea how you 'delete' an array in Java], the `copy` will be empty too" is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] copy = new int[N][N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    System.arrayCopy(original[i], 0, copy[i], 0, N);
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Java is JIT compiled, and the native code compiler can do all sorts of clever things to make simple loops go fast. So it is not obvious that a implementation of arraycopy makes a significant difference.

So the answer provided by @Brett Okken doesn't have to be faster than yours. But to be "sure" you can use his way. It's the "fastest".

```
System.arrayCopy(original[i], 0, copy[i], 0, N);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but maybe this is useful to most people:

IF YOU'RE JUST STORING THE DATA ON A NEW ARRAY BECAUSE THE ARRAY YOU'RE USING IS FULL, which means that the steps are:
1 -alloc a new and bigger array;
2 -copy the values from the older array to the new one;
3 -"point" the variable to the new array.

I've seen this algorithm:

```
int[][] newArray = new int[oldArray.length + 1][];
for (int n = oldArray.length; n-- != 0; newArray[n] = oldArray[n]) {}
oldArray = newArray;
```

The idea here is not to copy the values but to 'point' to them, this is specially usefull when the bigger structure is an 3d array. It seems that this algorithm is the fastest available.
This is not useful if you don't want to change the initial array, were, as it is obvious, the option is to send a copy of the original one.

It must be mentioned that I saw this code, or something close in an API named "fastUtil". It is available [here](https://github.com/vigna/fastutil)

Please feel free to correct me if I said any nonsense.